# Simian multiple excludes option

Tags: simian

I use Simian to analyze the duplicate codes in my c# project.
But I want to exclude two kind of situations.
One is unit test files shouldn't be analyzed, the other is auto-generated file (such as  Microsoft.Moles auto produces m.g.cs files)

My arguments are fine as following when I only have one kind of file excludes
-formatter=vs:c:\temp\SimianResult.log -language=cs $(SolutionDir)/**/*.cs -excludes=**/*Test.cs -threshold=15

But when I add the second situtions, I don't know how to put them together, I search it on the web ,but cannot find samples, even the offical site http://www.harukizaemon.com/simian/  doesn't show it. 
I try the following combination but all fails
    (1)... -excludes=**/*Test.cs,**/*m.g.cs -threshold=15
    (2)... -excludes=**/*Test.cs;**/*m.g.cs -threshold=15

    (3)... -excludes=**/*Test.cs **/*m.g.cs -threshold=15

Does anybody know how to solve it ? 
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My co-worker has try the correct syntax for me and it works. 
The key is your have to put the keyword "excludes" twice. So the answer of my question is 
    -formatter=vs:c:\temp\SimianResult.log -language=cs $(SolutionDir)/**/*.cs -excludes=**/*Test.cs -excludes=**/m.g.cs -threshold=15